# How to Load Data into Titan through Spark

Tags: graph, apache-spark, titan, gremlin-server

I want to load data into titanDB and i know about bulkloading and gremlin script will do that but i want to do the same using spark. i have data in json format and i want to load it using spark. They integrate the spark with titan in titan 0.9 and 1.0.0. but using SparkGraphComputer i can read the data from titan but i want to do opposite of it, i want to write data into titan using spark

References
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#sparkgraphcomputer

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/DGwJnpdHPmU

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: do you think its not a good question??

Comment: I did not understand it, but besides that, you did not provide examples for what you have tried. You did provide links to some documentation which indicates research on your behalf, but I don't think that's enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
ok i want to load data into titanDB and i know about bulkloading and gremlin script will do that but i want to do the same using spark. i have data in json format and i want to load it using spark. They integrate the spark with titan in titan 0.9 and 1.0.0. but using SparkGraphComputer i can read the data from titan but i want to do opposite of it, i want to write data into titan using spark

Comment: Better if you update your question. Regardless, I won't be able to help you as I'm not familiar with Titan. Still, update your question so others might.

Comment: sure thanks for helping me

Answer (score 3):

You need to use TinkerPop's `BulkLoaderVertexProgram`:

http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/titan-hadoop-tp3.html

You can see some examples of how it works in this Titan data migration sample repository:

https://github.com/dkuppitz/openflights

as well as this example for loading data via CSV:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gremlin-users/AetuGcLiBxo/KW966WAyAQAJ